# Big O proofing, need explanation on how to get the answer.

Tags: asymptotics, data-structure

I have spent the whole day trying to understand Big O but I'm still confused. Hopefully someone can enlighten me. I have an example: 
$100+5∈(^2)$ [so i know $100n+5$ is Big O of $n^2$]
[the image is the steps in solving the equation][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGauk.png)
So my question is: Why $n_0 = 15$ and $c =7$? How do I get it?

Comment: PLease see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: You can aswell take $c=105$ and $n_0=1$. Or for that matter you can take any $c$ and find the corresponding $n_0$